# Random occurrences of Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this system

Tags: xcode, macos

I have problems with running OSX applications with XCode. Sometimes (about 30% of the time) the application doesn't start and "*XCode cannot run using the selected / Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this system*." message is displayed instead.

This is NOT a duplicate of other questions, because this is not a problem with a project file (in such case the app would never run, and in my case the behaviour is random - sometimes it starts, sometimes not). This only happens with OSX applications.

XCode 5.0.2 (5A3005), OSX 10.9.3, but I had this problem since the first version of XCode 5 on both OSX 10.8 and 10.9.

Have you ever encountered similar issue?

Comment: What type of mac are you using? Architecture errors and Xcode 5 points to one of 2 things, either your projects are using libs/targets that don't handle fat bundles for 32 and 64bit architecture, or your using a power PC which has been long deprecated regarding OSX software support. Would you mind posting a screen shot of the error? Does the error appear when running the application or opening it? Xcode 5 had a big push to force debs to support 32 bit and 64 bit apps, I'm almost 100% sure this is related to your issue.

Comment: PowerPC, LOL! :) Have you read that I'm using OSX 10.9? Anyway, I am using MacBook Pro Retina, Mid 2012. The error is not showing up all the time:
1. I click Run in the Xcode - app runs OK
2. I click Run in the Xcode - app runs OK
3. I click Run in the Xcode - app runs OK
4. I click Run in the Xcode - error shows up
5. I click Run in the Xcode - app runs OK

So it's not really a machine/project issue. The error message is exactly the same as here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CGZO1.png

Comment: You'd be surprised how how many people I know that try to run unsupported software on unsupported hardware.

Comment: So after looking at the error message, is anything different regarding the target device when you run this? Is an iPod plugged in, an iTouch. On these devices, there are two targets now, a 64bit and a 32bit target (so you'll see your device show up twice if it's a 64bit device when plugging it into your computer). Or are you running on the simulator? Which simulator device are you using. I'm actually going to see if I can get the error trying to run Xcode 5 using the Xcode 4 simulator or something of the sort. I feel like I've seen that error before but I just knew the solution lol

Comment: I'm unsure in regards to how the above applies for OSX development (I'm an iOS developer), but I have a feeling it's a very similar issue. You should take a look into the answer I left below to check the supported architectures of your project. I'm willing to bet that sometimes it's running for 32 bit architecture and sometimes it's running for 64 bit.

Comment: One way to verify that it may be a bundle setting is by creating a brand new application and seeing if you can get the same results with that, if you can't... it's most likely a bundle setting in older projects created with older versions of Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and attempt to check these settings: [changing architecture settings](http://www.smikeapps.com/xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-device/). I have a feeling that sometimes your running on the 32 bit sim and sometimes the 64 bit sim so your running into the issue below.

Here's another link referencing how to change the standard Architecture for OSX: [Changing OSX Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724786/duplicated-target-xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-destination) and ensure you're no longer set to be using gcc and only using LLVM: [Other adjustments to bundle plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990774/xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-device-after-upgrade-to-xcode-5-0)